# MySQL: retrieve value from column of latest row

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to retreive the value of a specific column from a table, from the latest row (I have an `a.i` id column).

What query would need to be written in order to accomplish this?

So far I have...

```
$lots = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                  ->select('MAX(id) as num_lots')
                  ->from('my_table')
                  ->queryRow();
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: sorry just added, forgot to include my code segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

i.e. take the value from the first row of a table sorted by `id` in descending order.

---

EDIT:

As for your editted code - `MAX(id) as num_lots` in the `SELECT` clause selects the maximum value from the `id` column but that's probably not what you want.

In Yii you'd probably use something like this:

```
$lots = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
  ->select('column_name')
  ->from('my_table')
  ->order('id desc')
  ->limit(1)
  ->queryRow();
```

Comment: saw your original answer and it led me to this edit you just made! Thanks for he help. Chosen answer.